# Heroku cannot find jar when running clojure application

Tags: heroku, clojure

When following the Heroku clojure postgresql tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clojure-web-application

The app deploys and builds fine, but when run, it crashes, and gives the error:

```
2018-10-10T22:18:36.774956+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile target/bitjack-standalone.jar
```

My Pocfile is

```
web: java $JVM_OPTS -jar target/bitjack-standalone.jar
```

My project.clj is

```
(defproject bitjack "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
:description "FIXME: write description"
:url "http://example.com/FIXME"
:license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
          :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
               [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.6.1"]
               [org.postgresql/postgresql "9.4-1201-jdbc41"]
               [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.4.0"]
               [compojure "1.4.0"]
               [ring/ring-defaults "0.1.2"]
               [hiccup "1.0.5"]]
:main ^:skip-aot bitjack.web
:uberjar-name "bitjack-standalone.jar"
:plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.13"]]
:ring {:handler shouter.web//application
       :init shouter.models.migrations/migrated}
:profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
                                [ring-mock "0.1.5"]]}
           :uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

Building and running exactly the same locally works fine.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you check that you've committed your changes to git by running `git status`? Then make sure you're on the master branch.